# Mistakenly, I have deleted some of my nodejs code from the server(aws), how to recover it

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Mistakenly, I have deleted some of my nodejs code from the server(aws), how to recover it.Or from Filezilla, is there exist a way that i can undo the work that I have done some time ago.

Comment: Have you used git or any other version control software to track your work?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Can i recover it from AWS. Can AWS show the saved session with time Date. ? Can i reverse it from Filezilla.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do it, unless there was a backup enable for your server and the backup was taken just before you deleted the code

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have taken a backup, there is no method to recover the data. Your best bet would be to contact AWS support and see if they can help.